# Selenium Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently working on a python bot program that grabs 3 way odds(`home, draw, away`) of the same soccer match(same clubs) from two different bookie websites, then compares the odds and gets the large odds, the large odds are finally passed into an arbitrage calculator function named `oddchecker.py` to get the total implied probability. For example: `Osasuna vs Barcelona`, bookie site one has the three odds as: `4.60, 3.60, 1.90` and bookie two has odds as `4.70, 3.60, 1.87`, so my bot will grab`4.70, 3.60, 1.90`.

I'm using python and selenium for this project.

The bot is made up of four functions, namely `ab2.py, ab.py, main.py, and oddchecker.py`
Have imported `ab2.py, ab.py and oddchecker.py into main.py file` main.py is my main function to run the entire bot code.

`ab2.py` queries one bookie site and `ab.py` queries the other bookie site.

My code is able to grab the odds from the two sites and perform the comparison, **however it only prints** `home odd list`(i'm storing the odds in a list for comparison purposes) for the two teams when i run the `main.py`, **then code breaks and its unable to go back and grab for  odds for** `draw` and `away`.

Below is the error that i'm getting. Have done research regarding the error, and it seems that am making too many requests to the target server, i'm not sure if its a localhost port overuse or the target bookie servers. They say resolution is to implement sleep waits using `time.sleep(10)` module, in my code how can i implement that.

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=58202): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/1eaec216e17f72e3a4f30235093e0021/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F16BC30100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
None
```

Below is my code
`ab2.py`

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)
import time





def betika_func():
    web_betika= 'https://www.betika.com/s/soccer/spain-laliga'
    driver.get(web_betika)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    try:       
        btk_team1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="prebet-match"]//div[@class="prebet-match__odd-market__container"]//div[@class="prebet-match__teams"]//span[@class="prebet-match__teams__home"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')

        btk_team2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="prebet-match"]//div[@class="prebet-match__odd-market__container"]//div[@class="prebet-match__teams"]/span[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML')

        # odds = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="prebet-match"]//div[@class="prebet-match__odd-market__container"]//div[@class="prebet-match__odds__container"]//[@class="prebet-match__odds"]//button[@class="prebet-match__odd"]//span[@class="prebet-match__odd__odd-value"]')
   
        odds = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'prebet-match__odd__odd-value'))
        ) 

        hw = odds[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
        draw = odds[1].get_attribute('innerHTML')
        aw = odds[2].get_attribute('innerHTML')

        print(btk_team1)
        print(btk_team2)

        betika_home_odd = print('Betika home odd: '+hw)
        betika_draw_odd = print('Betika draw odd: '+draw)
        betika_away_odd = print('Betika away odd: '+aw)

        betika_dict = {
            'btk_home': hw,
            'btk_draw': draw,
            'btk_away': aw
        }

        return betika_dict

    finally:
        driver.quit()

# Testing the function
# response = betika_func()
# print(response)
```

ab.py code

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)


def odi_func():
    web_odi = 'https://odibets.com/'
    driver.get(web_odi)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)


    try:


    # Login form =================================================
    # btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="mobile-web-login"]')
    # btn.click()
    # print('Login form opened')

    # driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    # phone_num = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@placeholder="07xxxxxxxx or 01xxxxxxxx"]')
    # password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@placeholder="xxxxxxxx"]')
    # login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal"]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/button')
    # phone_num.send_keys()
    # password.send_keys()
    # login.click()
# ==============================
    # elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@href='/league'] [.//span[contains(.,'League')]])[1]")
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", elem)

        # Print the first soccer title
        # item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="l-events-games"]//div[@class="l-games-title"]//div[@class="l"]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
        # print('The first sport league or title is: '+item)

        # Get all clubs in the page.
        teams = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[2][@class="l-events-games"]//div[@class="l-events-games-matches"]//div[@class="l-games-event"]//a[@class="inf"]//div[@class="t-i"]')

        # Get the first two club names in the page
        odi_team1 = teams[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
        odi_team2 = teams[1].get_attribute("innerHTML")

        print(odi_team1)
        print(odi_team2)

        # Get three way odds
        odds = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[2][@class="l-events-games"]//div[@class="l-events-games-matches"]//div[@class="l-games-event"]//div[@class="mar-cont"]//span[@class="b"]')

        odi_hw = odds[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
        odi_draw = odds[1].get_attribute("innerHTML")
        odi_aw = odds[2].get_attribute("innerHTML")

    # print('Home odd for: '+team1+' is: '+odi_hw+' Draw odd is: '+odi_draw+ ' Away team is: '+team2+' Away win odd is: '+odi_aw)


        odi_home_odd = print('Odi home odd is: '+odi_hw)
        odi_draw_odd = print('Oddi draw odd is: '+odi_draw)
        odi_away_odd = print('Odi away odd is: '+odi_aw)

        odi_dict = {

            'odi_home': odi_hw,
            'odi_draw': odi_draw,
            'odi_away': odi_aw
        }

        return odi_dict
    
    finally:
        driver.quit()


# Testing the function
# response = odi_func()
# print(response)
```

oddchecker.py code

```
def func(odd1, odd2, odd3):

    implied1 = (1/odd1) * 100
    
    implied2 = (1/odd2) * 100
    
    implied3 = (1/odd3) * 100

    roundedodd1 = round(implied1, 2)
    roundedodd2 = round(implied2, 2)
    roundedodd3 = round(implied3, 2)

    totalimpliedprob = roundedodd1 + roundedodd2 + roundedodd3

    print('Implied prob for: '+str(odd1)+' is '+str(roundedodd1))
    print('Implied prob for: '+str(odd2)+' is '+str(roundedodd2))
    print('Implied prob for: '+str(odd3)+' is '+str(roundedodd3))

    totalimpliedprob = round(totalimpliedprob, 2)

    # print('Total implied odd market probability is: '+str(totalimpliedprob))
    return totalimpliedprob
    
    
# Testing the arbitrage function

# response = func(large_home_odd, large_draw_odd, large_away_odd)
# print(response)
```

Main.py code

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)

import time

import ab2 as betika
import ab as odi
import oddchecker as od


def main_func():

    try:


        home_list = []
        draw_list = []
        away_list = []


        time.sleep(20)
        odi_hm = odi.odi_func().get('odi_home')
        btk_hm = betika.betika_func().get('btk_home')
        home_list.append(odi_hm)
        home_list.append(btk_hm)
        print(home_list)

        time.sleep(20)
        odi_dr = odi.odi_func().get('odi_draw')
        btk_dr = betika.betika_func().get('btk_draw')
        home_list.append(odi_dr)
        draw_list.append(btk_dr)
        print(draw_list)

        time.sleep(20)
        odi_aw = odi.odi_func().get('odi_away')
        btk_aw = betika.betika_func().get('btk_away')
        home_list.append(odi_aw)
        draw_list.append(btk_aw)
        print(away_list)

        # Get the large home odd
        large_home_odd = max(home_list)
        large_draw_odd = max(draw_list)
        large_away_odd = max(away_list)


        # Pass the three maximum odds to arbitrage calculator, to check if total implied probability 
        # is equal or less than 100 percent

        final_response = od.func(large_home_odd, large_draw_odd, large_away_odd)
        print(final_response)
        print(str(large_home_odd))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

response = main_func()

print(response)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What error do you see?

Comment: THE error is in the post, the first code have typed, my code breaks. the tittle of the post is the error.

Comment: Any workaround brother?